# Android downloads corrupted

Tags: android, download

I have the following code to download large files from internet:

```
                try {
                    url = new URL(IPClass.SERVERIP + path[0].get(i) + "/" + fileName);

                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setReadTimeout(7000);
                    connection.connect();
                    fileLengthOnServer = connection.getContentLength();

                    input = connection.getInputStream();
                    output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Android/appdata/tmp/downloadtmp/" + fileName, true);

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    int count;

                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1 && applicationDownloadList.containsKey(fileName)) {
                        total = total + count;
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                        dl_progress = (int) ((total * 100L) / fileLengthOnServer);
                        applicationDownloadList.put(fileName, dl_progress);

                        if (total == fileLengthOnServer) {
                            downloadSuccessful();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (applicationDownloadList.containsKey(fileName)) {
                        doInBackground(appPathList);
                    }
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (output != null) output.close();
                        if (input != null) input.close();
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }
                    if (connection != null) {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                }
```

But sometimes not always the file downloads corrupted!
Can you please give me solutions to guarantee a successful download!

Answer (score 0):

You can prefer Sync Adapter for large downloads. This will download your file although your app is running or not .You can also show notification of download progress from it.